# How do I better structure Java code to avoid dereferencing null?

Tags: java, strings, null

I have the situation where as long as the user gives valid input, the StringBuilder object will not be null.

```
StringBuilder sb = null;
switch(userInput)
{
  case 1:
    sb = method1();
    break;
case 2:
    sb = method2();
    break;
case 3:
    sb = method3();
    break;
case 4:
    sb = method4();
    break;
default:
    System.out.println("invalid input"); 
}

System.out.println(sb.toString);//gives warning "dereferncing possible null pointer
```

Update: for those commenting it should be `String` instead of `StringBuilder` could you please explain? The method does a lot of appending so it needs to use String. Why would you bother converting to `String` if you can directly print out a `StringBuilder`? It seems like there's an implicit belief that a `StringBuilder` should always be converted to a `String`.

Comment: When you say : `The method does a lot of appending` do you refer to `method1` or actually the code your showing? I can get that `method1` does a lot of appending and could need an `StringBuilder`, but in the code your showing I don't see any `String` manipulation only a `sb.toString` (which should be `sb.toString()`)

Comment: Generic identifiers `method1` … `method4` make this [hypothetical code, which is off-topic for Code Review](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/9357). Please ask a follow-up question with real or realistic details.

Comment: @Marc-Andre I mean inside method1...method4 does a lot of appending.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to ensure that every statement in the `switch` is one that ensures that `sb != null` holds, this is not the case currently.

You can fix this by throwing an exception instead of logging a message, like this:

```
default:
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("input was invalid: " + userInput);
```

I also included that it tells you what the actual input was.

Other remarks are that your code has syntax errors, making it borderline ontopic, and your coding style definately needs improvement, I propose the following hence:

```
StringBuilder sb = null;
switch (userInput) {
    case 1:
        sb = method1();
        break;
    case 2:
        sb = method2();
        break;
    case 3:
        sb = method3();
        break;
    case 4:
        sb = method4();
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("input was invalid: " + userInput);
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Furthermore it seems very odd to me that your methods return a `StringBuilder`. I would just work with `String`s here, as you are not doing an extensive amount of string concatenation.

Short guide:

- `String`, to be used for regular text.
- `StringBuilder`, to be used when you need to concentate/append a lot of strings.
- `StringBuffer`, similar to `StringBuilder`, but now add to that that you are working in a multithreaded environment, hence you will almost never need this.

Comment: but `StringBuilder` is necessary inside method. Technically you're just wasting time converting it to a String to return. Can you explain your view some more?

Comment: @Celeritas How are you wasting time exactly? There are two scenarios: 1) You convert it before returning from `method1()`, which is the idiom that literally everyone is using. Or 2) You convert it after it has been returned, which you are using now. There is wasting time and besides that, it is nothing you should worry about, you should read up on *Premature Optimization*.

Comment: that's exactly what I'm trying to get at. Is it some sort of "idiom" to return a String than a StringBuilder? I'm saying it's a waste of time to typecast to String because I could just do System.out.println(myStringBuilder); which is all I need.

Comment: There is no "waste of time" since it will happen anyway in `println()`. What is more important is that your returning a builder when actually what you really need is a `String`. What is your goal of `method1` ? If it's building a `String` than build it and return it. The caller don't need to know that you're using a `StringBuilder` to create a `String`.

Answer (score 2):

In the `default` clause of your `switch` you are not setting `sb` to a non-null value. So it might still be null after the `switch`. You could change the `default` clause to set `sb` to something non-null, or throw an Exception like [@skiwi](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/32231/skiwi) suggested, which is a very good idea by the way.

Btw, you don't really need the `.toString()` call on a **StringBuilder**. This works fine too:

```
System.out.println(sb);
```

If its value is null, it will print the text "null".

Finally, I don't know what your complete code looks like, but if you're not using the **StringBuilder** returned by your `method1()`, `method2()`, ..., to build strings, then it might make sense to change those methods to return a simple **String** instead of a **StringBuilder**.

Comment: I'm up to hear your argument as to why `String` over `StringBuilder`. I guess I made the decision because if the string needed to be changed in the future it may be easier. Also it saves space in the code because instead of converting to `String` in each method.

Comment: Also how does that work you don't need `.toString()`? Is some sort of implicit type conversion happening?

Comment: @Celeritas `StringBuilder` is merely a mutable builder to build strings with, it (in itself) is not a `String`. You should only use it for building strings. "if the string needed to be changed in the future", is not a good argument to use a `StringBuilder`. The only good argument would be if you need to change the string *right now*, and then we are talking about 10+ times.

Comment: @skiwi no it's not like that. Inside the method the string gets changed a whole bunch and string builder is required. What I'm saying is may as well wait to the last possible minute to convert it to a string in case it needs to be changed, instead of returning a string from the method.

Comment: @Celeritas The outside code, like `sb = method1()`, doesn't care about the implementation, it doesn't need to add anything to that string anymore. Hence you should keep using a `StringBuilder` inside `method1()`, then build the `String` in the method and return it.

Comment: @Celeritas notice that I worded that paragraph very carefully. I can imagine cases where using a `StringBuilder` might make sense the way you did, but your short code snippet there looks unnatural, but maybe you have your reasons, that's up to you. As for `PrintStream.println`, it handles an `Object` parameter by calling `String.valueOf(o)`, which in turn calls `o.toString()`, that's why you don't need the explicit `.toString()` there.